# The results of different discretization rules in stochastic integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, probability, calculus, stochastic-processes

I have learned how to calculate different discretization rules in differential forms, but some papers prefer not to express the random terms in differential forms like
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x,t)+\xi(t).$$
In this form, I find it is hard to see where the discretization rules enter in the calculation. For example, when I see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0605471), the authors provide an appendix to explain the discretization rules, but I can't get the point. More specifically, the authors say if we know (A2)
$$W_{k}(x_{j+1},x_{j})=\tilde{n}(\bar{x}_{k})\exp\left[-\frac{\Delta}{2}\left(\frac{\epsilon_{k}}{\Delta}-F(\bar{x}_{k})\right)^{2}\Gamma(\bar{x}_{k})\right],$$
then we can get (A3)
$$\tilde{n}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\Gamma(x)}{2\pi\Delta}}\left(1-\frac{\Delta}{\Gamma}\left[\frac{\Gamma'(x)^{2}}{4\Gamma(x)^{2}}-\frac{\Gamma''(x)}{8\Gamma(x)}\right]\right)\left(1-\frac{\Delta}{2}F'(x)\right),$$
by the normalization condition (A4)
$$\int d x_{j+1}W_{k}(x_{j+1},x_{j})=1+O(\Delta^{2}),$$
where $\bar{x}_{k}=(x_{k}+x_{k+1})/2$, $\epsilon_{k}=x_{k+1}-x_{k}$ and $\Delta=t_{k+1}-t_{k}$. The functions $F(x)$ and $\Gamma(x)$ are arbitrary smooth functions. I don't know the meaning of the integral, if we integral $x_{j+1}$, it seems cannot get results. But if I change to integral $\epsilon_{k}$, I still can't obtain the results in the first round brackets of $\tilde{n}(x)$.

By the way, why the probability gets the results $1+O(\Delta^{2})$? If $O(\Delta^{2})>0$, it seems to break the definition of probability.

I would appreciate it if you could provide details of solutions to these questions.

Comment: I am having trouble to follow those authors' reasoning that a stochastic differential equation "remains ambiguous until we specify the limiting procedure associated with the discretization of time". That's wrong for SDEs as it is wrong for ODEs. It is enough to know that the SDE is in the Ito sense. See Kloeden & Platen *Numerical Solutions of Stochastic Differential Equations*. Your authors also seem to say that the associated Fokker Planck equation depends on their discretization scheme. Never heard of that.

Comment: @KurtG. Stochastic integrals can be defined in many ways, e.g. Ito vs Stratonovich, and the associated Fokker-Planck PDE indeed comes out different. Stratonovich is typically the more physically sensible version, but Ito is often more convenient when thinking in terms of martingales. One can move from one to the other by adding some extra terms to the SDE, but should you see an SDE like dX = adt + bdW in the wild, without further explanation, its meaning is in fact ambiguous. I believe this is what the authors are alluding to.

Comment: @alarge : you are right . My verdict was a bit too harsh. The SDE here however is quite simple. Assuming $\xi(t)$ is white noise it is $dx = f(x_t,t)\,dt + dW_t$ where $W$ is a standard Brownian motion. I do not really see why we need to make that fuzz about Ito vs Stratonovich since the equation is simply $x(t)=x(0)+\int_0^tf(x_s,s)\,ds+W_t$. Please correct me if I am wrong. Besides : the monstrous formulas in OP's post - I don't get what the authors' intention was with them. SDE $\leftrightarrow$ Focker Planck is standard. Can be learned from dozens of books.